# C# List<T> OrderBy float member

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a list that contain instances of class A.

```
class A
{
   public int Id;
   public float Value;
}

List<A> Collection = new List<A>( ... );
```

I want order the list using

```
Collection.OrderBy(item => item.Value);
```

This should be working but for float numbers it messes up the ordering. It will produce

```
1.0, 1.5, 1.6, 10.5, 11.54, 3.4, 4, 6.6, 7
```

Where 10.5, 11.54 should be at bottom the list.
This approach works perfectly for if Value were int. Any clue?

Comment: `Collection.OrderBy` will not modify the existing list, It will returnan ordered `IEnumerable<T>` do `var newList = Collection.OrderBy(item => item.Value).ToList()` and you will see the ordered list

Comment: @Habib, that is the correct and most complete answer. I will be upvoting your comment, but you should have posted it as an answer.

Comment: @MarkO, I wasn't sure about the OP's code, whether the OP has copied the whole line or just a piece of it. But I will be glad if the problem of the OP is solved :)

Comment: Silly mistake, you are right @Habib, I have to assign the sorted list back to its original list
`Collection = Collection.OrderBy(item => item.Value).ToList();`
Thanks for clearing that out, and you should have answered instead of a comment. Anyways voted

Answer (score 6):

Without creating a new list:

```
 Collection.Sort((x,y) => x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
List<A> Collection = new List<A>( ... );    
List<A> lstOrderedA = Collection.OrderBy(item => item.Value).ToList();
```

Here `lstOrderedA` will have the ordered list you are looking for.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any vote on your answer. No downvote , no Upvote.

Comment: @Habib There was an upvote on the answer but now it got removed. Hence, my question really is to whoever upvoted in the first place. My answer has not changed, so if it was sensible and correct 15 minutes ago, why not now?

Comment: Don't worry about the votes, +1, Your answer is correct. Some body just decided to undo the up vote, that happens.

Comment: @Habib I get that as that's not the first time its happened. I just wanted to know the reasoning why it 'ceased' to be a good solution suddenly?You know, what made it 'worthy' of the upvote in the first place and then not?

Comment: See this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94995/removing-an-up-vote-to-an-answer

Comment: The answers in this link are completely understandable and in this case, quite plausible too. No complaints from me!!!Also, there's always something to learn from stack overflow, sometimes technical, sometimes about human nature (+ves and -ves) and the way they think. I guess today is not that 'technical learning' kinda day for me!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
List<A> ResultList = Collection.OrderBy(item => item.Value).ToList();
```

U can use Linq query syntax too:

```
IEnumerable<A> c = from x in Collection
                   orderby x.Value
                   select x;
```

Comment: The order by and subsequent `ToList()` gives you a `List<A>`. Not an `IEnumerable<T>`. This wont even compile. And do we really need another answer for this very basic question?

Comment: How is link more better? They both compile the same, only difference is syntax, and that is just a matter of opinion.

Comment: @moez Please elaborate on `"the LINK seems to be more powerful"`?

Comment: @DGibbs `List` implements `IEnumerable` so it's fine to assign a list to an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: yes and this: `IEnumerable<A> b = collection.OrderBy(v => v.Value).ToList();` compiles just fine :)

Comment: @albertjan No, the line was literally `IEnumerable<T> b = collection.OrderBy(v => v.Value).ToList();` which does not compile (unless a generic method)

Comment: Yes it was an error of typing and i changed it to A and as @albertjan implements  IEnumerable

Comment: moez: Please don't assume that certain people down voted you; anyone else could have been voting as @DGibbs left the comment. And your reaction here is one of the big reasons people *don't* leave comments when they do down vote.

Answer (score 0):

i use this code :

```
List<A> Collection = new List<A>() 
{
    new A(){Id=1,Value=1.0f},new A(){Id=1,Value=11.5f},new A(){Id=1,Value=1.6f},new A(){Id=1,Value=10.5f}
};
List<A> orderedList =  Collection.OrderBy(i =>i.Value).ToList();
```

and it show
1.0,1.6,10.5,11.5.

Answer (score 0):

This proves that it does work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ryECS

Linq however doesn't change the original list it returns a new sorted `IEnumerable<A>`

So after calling `.OrderBy(a => a.Value)` the value of `collection` stays the same.

As explained in another answer if you want to change the original list you should use `Sort`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{   

    class A
    {
       public int Id;
       public float Value;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var collection = new List<A>{
            new A { Id = 1, Value = 1.0f },
            new A { Id = 5, Value = 5.0f },
            new A { Id = 6, Value = 6.0f },
            new A { Id = 10, Value = 10.0f },
            new A { Id = 11, Value = 11.0f },
            new A { Id = -289, Value = -289.0f },
            new A { Id = 123, Value = 123.0f },
            new A { Id = 3, Value = 3.0f }
        };

        foreach (var a in collection.OrderBy(v => v.Value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
-289
1
3
5
6
10
11
123
```